example of a definable type over a set, which cannot be canonically extended to a global definable type through definition
When $M$ is a model, a definable type of $M$ can be canonoically extended to a global type by its definition. However, when $A$ is a set, it might not be the case. I am looking for an example, which is a definable type over a set, but any of its definition does not extend to be a definition of some global type.
This is an exercise in Chernikov's stability theory notes (Exercise 3.7.6), but I need this example mainly to justify a definition in a research paper.

Consider the theory $T$ in the language $\{P\}$, where $P$ is a unary predicate, which says there are infinitely many elements, but $P$ is true of exactly two of them. Let $M$ be a model and $A\subseteq M$ such that $A$ is disjoint from $P(M) = \{b,c\}$. Note that $b$ and $c$ have the same type over $A$.
Let $p\in S_x(A)$ be the type of an element satisfying $P$ (so it includes $P(x)$ and $x\neq a$ for all $a\in A$). The theory is stable, so $p$ is definable over $A$. Pick such a definition and let $q\in S_x(M)$ be the set of formulas (it won't be a consistent type!) obtained by applying the definition to arbitrary parameters in $M$.
Let $\varphi(x,y)$ be $x = y$, and consider the defining $L(A)$-formula $d_p\varphi(y)$. Since $b$ and $c$ have the same type over $A$, either both satisfy $d_p\varphi(y)$ or neither does. In the first case, $q$ contains $x = b$ and $x = c$, so it is inconsistent. In the second case, $q$ contains $P(x)$ and $x\neq b$ and $x\neq c$, so it is inconsistent.

Thank you! I was writing about an example of DLO and I think this should also work(?): In DLO, let $p(x,y)\in S_2(\varnothing)$ be a complete type containing $x<y$, $\exists z(z<x)$, $\exists z(z>y)$. Any global type extending $p(x,y)$ is not $\varnothing$-invariant, because it corresponds to a realized or non-realized cut $(L,R)$ with both $L$ and $R$ nonempty, when restricted to a small model. However, any $\varnothing$-definable type must be $\varnothing$-invariant.

@RoastedFish In DLO, every type over a set $A$ has a global $A$-invariant extension. Note that $\forall x\exists z(z<x)$ is provable in DLO, so every type over a model $M$ contains the formula $\exists z(z<x)$, regardless of whether there is some $m\in M$ such that $m<x$ is in the type. Your type $p(x,y)$ extends to a global $\varnothing$-invariant type containing $x<y<m$ for all $m$ in the monster model.

@RoastedFish But you can do something similar in the circular order: the unique type over $\varnothing$ is trivially definable over $\varnothing$, but it has no global $\varnothing$-invariant extension.

Thank you again for your reply! I realized that DLO actually never works as an example for this question, because the only two definable non-realized global types are the type at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

@RoastedFish Those are the only two definable over $\varnothing$, yes. The type which says $a<x$ and $x<b$ for all $b>a$ is non-realized and definable over ${a}$.
